# Talend csv to relational db tables : foreign key setting

Tags: join, relational-database, talend

I'm a Talend beginner and searched about this simple problem, many have posted the web about the same problem but no solution appeared...

I have a csv file with 50 fields, I want to load it into  a three tables relational database with Talend. I did a tMap, everything is ok except for foreign key : I don't know how to set them.

Here is my job
[image]
Here is my tMap
[image]

I hope someone could give me the simple exact solution

Cheers

Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two Time.

`(CSV) -> (tmap) -> (organisation_output)
  |
subjobok
  |
  |    (organisation_input)
  |         |
 (CSV) -> (tmap)-> (country and adress output)`

Do a INNER JOIN in the second tmap on column that have unique value for each row.
And load 'ImpID' of your organisation input in  the two other output table Impid column.